# Android 4.0 Different Screen Size and Density

Tags: android

This is main activity screen of my application.But I do not provide same view in different screen size and density.Please help me.How can I solve this problem.I want to use this xml layout with android API 10 and higher.I tried most of techniques solve this problem but I did not.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:background="@drawable/home"
>



<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/topheader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="142dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="320dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/include3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        layout="@layout/anaekran_seconddock" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/include2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        layout="@layout/anaekran_firstdock" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
        layout="@layout/anaekran_thirddock" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="142dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topheader"
    android:background="@color/gray" >

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You mean to say that your layout doesn't get visible in device containing the api 10 or above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create different xml files for different screen sizes and put them in their respective folders .

for example for medium screen size put the .xml in res/layout-medium folder.
for large--- res/layout-large
for extralarge---res/layout-xlarge

the name of all the xml files must be same in all the folders.
for more information read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can not specify a certain layout for a certain API leverl. You can limit you application to be run on minimum and maximum API levels using the following in your manifest file:

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

if you want to use particular layouts for certain screen sizes you can do that by putting different layout xml files in the res/layout-land or res/layout-normal or res/layout-large, ect.